# filters in Android returning anything

Tags: java, android

i have an ArrayList in which I'm using filters to get the search results. I wanted to place a text **"No Results Found"** if the query don't return anything and if it returns results then remove the above text (noResultFoundTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE); )

Could you please tell me how to implement it?

My menu creation is done like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the rest of your code and I can further explain as to what you are trying to do.

Not sure what "public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)" and " public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)" is supposed to do, but if that is part of the filters implementation, then you must return true if the query text has been found with the filter.

You can ust the examples below to return true if the value has been found

To use List Filters

```
list.stream().filter(string -> string.contains(filterString)).findFirst().orElseGet("No Results Found");
```

Or if you get NullPointerExceptions, try

```
try {
    return list.stream().filter(string -> string.contains(filterString)).findFirst();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return "No Results Found";
}
```